# Shutdown request received

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,I am using laser assembler package for 2D pointCloud to 3D point-cloud conversion. First I am start launch file (laser.launch), then followed by I'll run cpp file, when I run .cpp file  suddenly the roslaunch(master) file will be shutdown, the error is

```
[ WARN] [1375768306.726458068]: Shutdown request received.
[ WARN] [1375768306.726502466]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
```

launch file is

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="laser_assembler" type="laser_scan_assembler" output="screen"  name="laser_scan_assembler">
    <remap from="/scan" to="tilt_scan"/>
    <param name="tf_cache_time_secs" type="double" value="11.0" />
    <param name="max_scans" type="int" value="400" />
    <param name="ignore_laser_skew" type="bool" value="true" />
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="/sr_lidar1_scan" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71344/shutdown-request-received/) by [sivan chinnaiyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/5404/sivan-chinnaiyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-08-07**:
How could a .cpp file be run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible that you run a .cpp file from the "laser_scan_assembler" ? I think you start the same node again, which ends in an shutdown because you have the same name twice.
If you wanna run it both together then change the name in the .launch file, e.g to "laser_scan_assembler_1"

---

Originally posted by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) with karma: 336 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sivan chinnaiyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/5404/sivan-chinnaiyan/) on 2013-08-07**:
thanks Mr.coon, if i change the .launch file node name ,, is .cpp file run time error occurred for [ERROR] [1375875020.161393352]: Need to set parameter fixed_frame

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-08-07**:
Have you read the [laser_assembler doc](http://ros.org/wiki/laser_assembler#Parameters)? It states the `laser_scan_assembler` requires a parameter fixed_frame.

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-08**:
I was running the same node in two launch files, one in my gazebo world launch file and one in the controller launch file. The gazebo launch file would init the node and the controller launch would kill it. Thank you!